# How do you pass startup options to Jenkins on Ubuntu when it has been installed through snap?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, port

I have installed `Jenkins` on `Ubuntu 2020.10` with `snap`. I want to change the default port from `8080` to something else. I can see in `/var/snap/jenkins` that there is `config.xml` but I can't see any way to set the HTTP port in there. I can't find any documentation for `config.xml` either.

Searching for this I see lots of suggestions to modify `/etc/default/jenkins`, but this doesn't exist as it's a snap installation.

How can I to modify the startup port for Jenkins installed on Ubuntu via Snap?